# GIFs are Sent as Videos in Telegram Using grammy Library

Tags: typescript, telegram, telegram-bot, grammy

We are developing a Telegram bot using the `grammy` library and have encountered an issue: when attempting to send GIF files using the `sendAnimation` method from the `grammy` documentation, they are being sent and displayed as videos in Telegram, instead of animations.

We have verified that the files are indeed in GIF format. Could anyone suggest a solution or explain why this is happening? Perhaps someone has faced a similar issue.

Link to grammy documentation: [Grammy Documentation](https://grammy.dev/guide/files)

```js
async function sendChallengeAnimation(
    ctx: CommandContext<Context>
): Promise<void> {
    const randomAnimationNumber =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * challengeAnimationsCount) + 1
    const video = InputMediaBuilder.video(
        new InputFile(`media/challenge/${randomAnimationNumber}.gif`)
    )
    await ctx.replyWithMediaGroup([video])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question gets at functions relying on more of the Telegram rather than the Grammy side and docs can be found [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files).

In addition to the `Photo`, `Video`, `MediaGroup` and other media types in Telegram, there is also the `Animation` type. Try substituting `MediaGroup` for `Animation`.

If that doesn't work or you need the MediaGroup type, try substituting the `video` in `InputMediaBuilder.video` for `animation`.

[Here's](https://deno.land/x/grammy@v1.19.2/mod.ts?s=InputMediaBuilder) some more relevant docs for that last bit.